# Adapting an animated canvas element into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm currently trying to convert a canvas element that has a looping animation into a React project as a component, and struggling to figure out the best way to adapt it over. I've been mainly using this article as a guide (https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258) and it looks like useRef() could be a good tool here but I'm struggling to figure out how to structure the component.

This is the code I'm attempting to convert:

```
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    dashLen = 220, dashOffset = dashLen, speed = 5,
    txt = "STROKE-ON CANVAS", x = 30, i = 0;

ctx.font = "50px Comic Sans MS, cursive, TSCu_Comic, sans-serif"; 
ctx.lineWidth = 5; ctx.lineJoin = "round"; ctx.globalAlpha = 2/3;
ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "#1f2f90";

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(x, 0, 60, 150);
  ctx.setLineDash([dashLen - dashOffset, dashOffset - speed]); // create a long dash mask
  dashOffset -= speed;                                         // reduce dash length
  ctx.strokeText(txt[i], x, 90);                               // stroke letter

  if (dashOffset > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop);             // animate
  else {
    ctx.fillText(txt[i], x, 90);                               // fill final letter
    dashOffset = dashLen;                                      // prep next char
    x += ctx.measureText(txt[i++]).width + ctx.lineWidth * Math.random();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3 * Math.random());        // random y-delta
    ctx.rotate(Math.random() * 0.005);                         // random rotation
    if (i < txt.length) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
})();

<canvas width=630></canvas>
```

Really appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly a lot of ways you could do this. Me personally, I wouldn't use ref. Ref is really only useful for functions that happen as a reaction to something (like clicking a button, changing a field's value).

Since we need the context, and want to set up a render loop, we'll want to be able to know when the canvas has been created. For this, we'll use `useState` and pass the setter to the canvas' `ref` property. The animation loop will setup inside an effect. We need to keep track of wether or not the component is still mounted, so we use a local variable in the effect to keep track of this (and if we're not mounted, we short-circuit the animation frame).

```js
function CanvasComponent() {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // On the first render, canvas won't be set. However, once setCanvas is called by ref, this effect will run again.
    if (canvas == null) return;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const dashLen = 220;
    let dashOffset = dashLen;
    const speed = 5;
    const txt = "STROKE-ON CANVAS";
    let x = 30;
    let i = 0;

    ctx.font = "50px Comic Sans MS, cursive, TSCu_Comic, sans-serif";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 2 / 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "#1f2f90";
    
    // Keep track of wether the component is still mounted
    let mounted = true;

    const loop = () => {
      if (!mounted) return;
      ctx.clearRect(x, 0, 60, 150);
      ctx.setLineDash([dashLen - dashOffset, dashOffset - speed]); // create a long dash mask
      dashOffset -= speed; // reduce dash length
      ctx.strokeText(txt[i], x, 90); // stroke letter

      if (dashOffset > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop); // animate
      else {
        ctx.fillText(txt[i], x, 90); // fill final letter
        dashOffset = dashLen; // prep next char
        x += ctx.measureText(txt[i++]).width + ctx.lineWidth * Math.random();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3 * Math.random()); // random y-delta
        ctx.rotate(Math.random() * 0.005); // random rotation
        if (i < txt.length) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      }
    };

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    
    // React will call this function when the effects' dependencies change, or the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      // Set mounted to false so that the next frame is short-circuited.
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [canvas]);

  return <canvas width="630" ref={setCanvas}></canvas>;
}
```

Hope this helps.

P.S.

I don't know if it's intentional or not, but in your code, `i` is never updated.